# How to prepare lubuntu for pro audio production?

Tags: sound, kernel, lubuntu, ubuntu-studio, audio-recording

I installed lubuntu 19.10 and now i want to configure for pro audio production. How do I install the lowlatency kernel? I read that I need to install ubuntu studio controls and cjacktl. Is that all I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UbuntuStudioInstaller
suggests

```
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer
```

Running the installer includes options for low-latency kernel (*see provided wiki page*).

Comment: Works pretty well, but does install a large number of applications...

Comment: I realize that, but a lot of work has gone into Ubuntu Studio's configurations and thus I'm unwilling to *guess* consequences with installing less (*or look further*).  It's likely not what the OP hopes for, but it will solve it I believe.

Comment: I think the largest obstacle would be that there is not a coherent guide to how to use all of the components available.  I believe that there is an assumption that someone installing UbuntuStudio has an understanding of how audio production works, and a good grasp of inter program communications

Comment: Charles, Ubuntu Studio Installer only installs what one selects, so installing it and the very basic configurations does not install "a large number of applications." Also, we've put a lot of work into making the configuration work so the user doesn't have to, and ubuntustudio-installer (and the items one selects to install from it) does the legwork for the user. Of course, the applications that one can install do assume the user has production knowledge, but doesn't any professional production application?